# Migrate a git repo to a folder in a different repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have two projects, A and B, each with their own repo.

A: http://url.repo.a.com

> ```
> ./folder1
> ./folder2
> ```

B: http://url.repo.b.com

> ```
>   ./foo
>   ./bar
> ```

I want to migrate everything from repo A into repo B in it's own folder. I'd like to preserve history, but only care about moving master from repo A, I don't need all branches. After, it should look like this:

B: http://url.repo.b.com

> ```
> ./foo
> ./bar
> ./new_folder
>     ./folder1
>     ./folder2
> ```

Ideally i'd like to do this in a new branch in repo B so I can make sure everything works before I merge to master. I'd also be dealing with a non-master branch for A in case I mess anything up. I'm not very familiar with git though and am having some trouble figuring out how to do this. I did some searching around and tried this, but I get errors about "couldn't find remote ref". Any tips?

> ```
> cd a
> git checkout -b a_branch
> cd b
> git checkout -b b_branch
> mkdir new_folder
> cd new_folder
> git remote add a_branch http://url.repo.a.com
> git fetch a_branch
> git merge a_branch b_branch
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To move master branch of repoA into repoB in new_folder, you can use below commands:

```
# In repoB
git checkout -b newBranch
git subtree add --prefix=new_folder/ http://url.repo.a.com master
git checkout master
git merge newBranch
```

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.